# How to implement commenting system using ASP.NET repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, comments, repeater

I already implemented but I am facing only one problem. As repeater show all comments according to my query to database and there is a delete button showing in every item of repeater but the delete button should need to appear only at that item(comment) which is commented by the logged-in user. Now a user can delete any other user's comment, how to avoid it. I mean to say to how hide delete button from all repeater results except the logged-in user's comments?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please post your code. So that we have enough idea what you are trying to do